# Docker swarm ignores iptables=false flag

Tags: docker, iptables, docker-swarm, swarm, ufw

I'm trying to setup a docker swarm, but I want to use `ufw` to create my own network rules. I've tried both putting `--iptables=false` in the docker service file, and also putting `{ "iptables": false }` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.

However, whenever I deploy a service e.g.

```
docker service create -p 80:80 nginx:alpine
```

I still get the following output whenever I run

```
sudo iptables -L | grep -i docker

=>
696 39904 DOCKER-USER    all -- any   any  anywhere  anywhere
696 39904 DOCKER-INGRESS all -- any   any  anywhere  anywhere
Chain DOCKER-INGRESS (1 references)
Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
```

Docker version: `18.01.0-ce` (installed with https://get.docker.com)

OS: `Ubuntu 16.04`

Is there anything i'm not seeing?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: still a problem with docker 18.09-ce :/

Comment: filed a bug on the swarm github: https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/2917